# How to link generated c code to mps editor in Jetbrain's MPS

Tags: mps

I am not sure if this functionality is available or not but can anyone please answer whether can I link generated c code to MPS editor code in Jetbrain's MPS.

Comment: MPS per se does not generate C code. Mbeddr, which is based on MPS does that. See mbeddr.com

Comment: Yes but is it possible?